# Class Function Call

Tags: javascript, class, function

I have a class setup as follows:

```
var oTest = new TEST();

function TEST() {

  this.String = function(sString) {

    this.Trim = function() {
    }
  }
}
```

I want to be able to call the Trim function as follows:

```
var sTrimmed = oTest.String("  something").Trim();
```

Is this the correct approach?  Any help would be greatly appreciated as i have never done functions inside class functions before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your methods to the `prototype` of the constructor function, and do `return this;` in `String`, to return the same object, which makes it chainable.

```
var oTest = new TEST();

function TEST() {}

TEST.prototype.String = function(aString) {
    this.the_string = aString;
    return this;
};
TEST.prototype.Trim = function() {
    this.the_string = this.the_string.trim();
    return this;
};
TEST.prototype.getString = function() {
    return this.the_string;
};

var sTrimmed = oTest.String("  something")
                    .Trim()
                    .getString();
```

***live demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/BcwgC/